# Bash: Keep all lines with duplicate values in column X

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file with a few thousand lines and 20+ columns. I now want to keep only the lines that have the same e-mail address in column 3 as in other lines.

file: (First Name; Last Name; E-Mail; ...)

```
Mike;Tyson;mike@tyson.com
Tom;Boyden;tom@boyden.com
Tom;Cruise;mike@tyson.com
Mike;Myers;mike@tyson.com
Jennifer;Lopez;jennifer@lopez.com
Andre;Agassi;tom@boyden.com
Paul;Walker;paul@walker.com
```

I want to keep ALL lines that have a matching e-mail address. In this case the expected output would be

```
Mike;Tyson;mike@tyson.com
Tom;Boyden;tom@boyden.com
Tom;Cruise;mike@tyson.com
Mike;Myers;mike@tyson.com
Andre;Agassi;tom@boyden.com
```

If I use

```
awk -F';' '!seen[$3]++' file
```

I will lose the first instance of the e-mail address, in this case line 1 and 2 and will keep ONLY the duplicates.

Is there a way to keep all lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the output order doesn't matter, here's a one-pass approach:

```
$ awk -F';' '$3 in first{print first[$3] $0; first[$3]=""; next} {first[$3]=$0 ORS}' file
Mike;Tyson;mike@tyson.com
Tom;Cruise;mike@tyson.com
Mike;Myers;mike@tyson.com
Tom;Boyden;tom@boyden.com
Andre;Agassi;tom@boyden.com
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly. The list can be ordered (again) afterwards, no problem.

Comment: I know stackoverflow doesn't like this kind of question. Still I'll try it: Is there a way to change the code so that the output only shows the first (instead of all) instance of the lines with duplicate mail addresses?

Comment: Yes. there is a huge clue in the name of the array where to find the **first** instance. Really **think** about what each of the 4 statements in the above do. Add additional debugging prints if necessary to better understand the code. Try removing what you think represents the text you don't want printed. See my comments under [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63995109/1745001) for how to get help if after trying to make the change yourself you're still stuck.

Answer (score 6):

This awk one-liner will help you:

```
awk -F';' 'NR==FNR{a[$3]++;next}a[$3]>1' file file
```

It passes the file twice, the first time it calculates the count of occurrence, the 2nd pass will check and output.

With the given input example, it prints:

```
Mike;Tyson;mike@tyson.com
Tom;Boyden;tom@boyden.com
Tom;Cruise;mike@tyson.com
Mike;Myers;mike@tyson.com
Andre;Agassi;tom@boyden.com
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, in a single read Input_file in single `awk`.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=";"
}
{
  mail[$3]++
  mailVal[$3]=($3 in mailVal?mailVal[$3] ORS:"")$0
}
END{
  for(i in mailVal){
    if(mail[i]>1){ print mailVal[i] }
  }
}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                                  ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                                                 ##Starting BEGIN section of this program from here.
  FS=";"                                               ##Setting field separator as ; here.
}
{
  mail[$3]++                                           ##Creating mail with index of 3rd field here and keep adding its value with 1 here.
  mailVal[$3]=($3 in mailVal?mailVal[$3] ORS:"")$0     ##Creating mailVal which has 3rd field as index and value is current line and keep concatinating to it wiht new line.
}
END{                                                   ##Starting END block of this program from here.
  for(i in mailVal){                                   ##Traversing through mailVal here.
    if(mail[i]>1){ print mailVal[i] }                  ##Checking condition if value is greater than 1 then printing its value here.
  }
}
' Input_file                                           ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 1):

I think @ceving just needs to go a little further.

*ASSUMING* the chosen column is NOT the first or last -

```
cut -f$col -d\; file             |      # slice out the right column
  tr '[[:upper:]]' '[[:lower:]]' |      # standardize case
  sort | uniq -d                 |      # sort and output only the dups
  sed 's/^/;/; s/$/;/;'          > dups # save the lowercased keys
grep -iFf dups file > subset.csv        # pull matching records
```

This breaks if the chosen column is the first or last, but should otherwise preserve case and order from the original version.

If it *might* be the first or last, then pad the stream to that last grep and clean it afterwards -

```
sed 's/^/;/; s/$/;/;' file       |            # pad with leading/trailing delims
  grep -iFf dups                 |            # grab relevant records
sed 's/^;//; s/;$//;'            > subset.csv # strip the padding
```

Comment: This is noisy and could be simplified, I'm sure, but it doesn't break on embedded metacharacters, case variance, or isolated hits. :).

Comment: It does still have the problem [you identified earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63992814/bash-keep-all-lines-with-duplicate-values-in-column-x#comment113160281_63993195) that if an email address can also show up in another column then there could be a false match

Comment: The problem is more complex than immediately apparent in the spec, lol. Looking forward to having enough free time to fix that too. :)

Answer (score 0):

Find the duplicate e-mail addresses:

```
sed -s 's/^.*;/;/;s/$/$/' < file.csv | sort | uniq -d > dups.txt
```

Report the duplicate csv rows:

```
grep -f dups.txt file.csv
```

**Update:**

As "Ed Morton" pointed out the above commands will fail, when the e-mail addresses contain characters, which have a special meaning in a regular expression.  This makes it necessary to escape the e-mail addresses.

One way to do so is to use Perl compatible regular expression. In a PCRE the escape sequences `\Q` and `\E` mark the beginning and the end of a string, which should not be treated as a regular expression.  GNU grep supports PCREs with the option `-P`. But this can not be combined with the option `-f`. This makes it necessary to use something like `xargs`. But `xargs` interprets backslashes and ruins the regular expression.  In order to prevent it, it is necessary to use the option `-0`.

Lessen learned: it is quite difficult to get it right without programming it in AWK.

```
sed -s 's/^.*;/;\\Q/;s/$/\\E$/' < file.csv | sort | uniq -d | tr '\n' '\0' > dups.txt
xargs -0 -i < dups.txt grep -P '{}' file.csv
```

Comment: That grep will produce false matches as `bar@example.com` would match `foobar@example.com`.

Comment: @EdMorton Try it out and you will see, that it will not produce false matches.

Comment: I see what you did. The `sed` makes your pattern file start with `;` delimiters and end with `$` - no false positives.

Comment: Try it when the input file contains duplicate `mr.jones@foo.com` and single `mrsjones@foo.com`. You're right that that first example I gave wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: It also needs a way to select an arbitrary column.

Comment: @thanasisp no it can't because you need the `$` anchor (or something else) to avoid a different problem. Also the OP said in their real data they have 20+ columns so then Pauls comment about only matching in one column becomes very relevant.

Comment: Right. Changing `s/$/$/` to `s/$/;/` should fix that too but we're kind peeling the onion.