# Bash: Keep first line with duplicate values in column X

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file with a few thousand lines and 20+ columns. I now want to identify the lines that have the same e-mail address in column 3 as in other lines BUT only keep the first line with this e-mail address.

file: (First Name; Last Name; E-Mail; ...)

```
Mike;Tyson;mike@tyson.com
Tom;Boyden;tom@boyden.com
Tom;Cruise;mike@tyson.com
Mike;Myers;mike@tyson.com
Jennifer;Lopez;jennifer@lopez.com
Andre;Agassi;tom@boyden.com
Paul;Walker;paul@walker.com
```

For every e-mail duplicate in column 3 I only want to keep the FIRST line. I don't want to keep the lines where the e-mail address is unique.

In this case the expected output would be

```
Mike;Tyson;mike@tyson.com
Tom;Boyden;tom@boyden.com
```

If I use

```
awk -F';' '!seen[$3]++' file
```

I will lose the first instance of the e-mail address, in this case line 1 and 2 and will keep ONLY the duplicates. What I'm looking for is basically the exact opposite: lose all duplicates but keep only the first instance.

A solution with awk would be great but I can't figure out how to also keep the first line (not ONLY the duplicates). Does anyone know how to do that?

Thanks,
Patrick

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bash: Keep all lines with duplicate values in column X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63992814/bash-keep-all-lines-with-duplicate-values-in-column-x)

Comment: Please **DO NOT** post same question multiple times: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63992814/bash-keep-all-lines-with-duplicate-values-in-column-x

Comment: @LéaGris it is not the same question (I understand it may look the same at first glance, but I also followed the first episode, I guess it's just a Series).

Comment: @KamilCuk what do you think I'm doing? ;) After having been stuck on this problem for 1-2 hours and not finding a solution on stackoverflow I will post it as a question.

Comment: @Léa Gris it is a related question but not the same one.

Comment: @Ed Morton it might be trivial to you but not to me. Also stackoverflow asks the OP to post only one question per thread. That's why I opened two different threads.

Comment: The question was closed due to "not being focused enough". There is only one question in the post and it hasn't been solved yet. How can I reopen the question?

Comment: @Patrick the problem with this question is your starting point is exactly the same starting point as for your previous question instead of this one starting with your attempt at modifying one of the solutions to your previous question. You've now accepted an answer to your previous question. IMHO the code in that answer is very clear and simple and the required modification is extremely obvious so **try** yourself to modify it to do what you now want and if you can't **then** post a new question (or update this one) with your attempts at that as the starting point.

Comment: @Patrick If you just pipe the output of an answer of your previous question to the famous awk idiom you include into this question, you will have one answer already. Just think of what each one is doing on its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Perl to print the first occurrence of each email with more than 1 occurrence in the input *in the input order*. As per the OP's comment:

> "I'm only looking for the first line with e-mail duplicates. In this case I want to get rid of all lines with e-mail addresses that only occur once/are unique. So no `paul@walker.com` or `jennifer@lopez.com`."

```
# Create the input file:

cat > in.txt <<EOF
Mike;Tyson;mike@tyson.com
Tom;Boyden;tom@boyden.com
Tom;Cruise;mike@tyson.com
Mike;Myers;mike@tyson.com
Jennifer;Lopez;jennifer@lopez.com
Andre;Agassi;tom@boyden.com
Paul;Walker;paul@walker.com
EOF
```

```
cat in.txt | perl -F';' -lane 'my $email = $F[2]; unless ( $seen{$email}++ ) { $line_for{$email} = $_; push @emails, $email; } END { for my $email ( @emails ) { print $line_for{$email} if $seen{$email} > 1; }  }; '
```

Prints:

```
Mike;Tyson;mike@tyson.com
Tom;Boyden;tom@boyden.com
```

---

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.
`-a` : Split `$_` into array `@F` on whitespace or on the regex specified in `-F` option.
`-F';'` : Split into `@F` on semicolon, rather than on whitespace.

`%seen` : hash with keys = emails, and values = number of occurrences.
`$seen{ $F[2] }++` : increment by 1 the number of occurrences of the email (3rd field, index of this field is `2`). Before the email is seen for the first time,  the value is `undef` and it evaluates to false in boolean context. So the original input line is stored in the hash element: `$line_for{$email} = $_;`, and the email is stored in the array `@emails`, in the order of appearance in the input. After the email has been seen, its value is 1 or more, and evaluates to true. So the line is not stored.
`END { ... }` : Execute the code after all input has been read, before exiting.
`print $line_for{$email} if $seen{$email} > 1;` : If the number of occurrences of the email is more than one (if it is a duplicate), print the original line for this email, the first one that was found in the input.

**SEE ALSO:**

[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)

Comment: `perl -pe 'tr/;/\t/'` No need for `perl`, just `tr`.

Comment: @KamilCuk Thank you, will add this alternative to the answer. BTW, is `tr` faster than `perl` here?

Comment: is a tool specifically created for replacing characters faster then the whole language interpreter? Probably yes, knowing perl the difference is going to be negligible. The issue is with portability - I have _a lot_ of machines without perl.

Comment: @KamilCuk OK, thank you, this makes sense. BTW, what scripting languages do these machines have if even Perl is missing? Python 3.7, etc?

Comment: @KamilCuk Thank you for suggesting using a simpler and faster `tr` instead of `perl` for simple character replacement.

Comment: @TimurShtatland `awk` is the scripting language that's required to exist on all POSIX compliant Unix boxes, just like sed, grep, tr, cat, etc. Most Unix boxes I've worked on in the past only had mandatory Unix tools so they had awk but no perl, python, etc. Btw the OP is trying to print the first line for every set of duplicate email addresses but not print anything for email addresses that are not duplicated so the expected output in the question is the correct output, no `Jennifer;Lopez;jennifer@lopez.com` for example.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm only looking for the first line with e-mail duplicates. In this case I want to get rid of all lines with e-mail addresses that only occur once/are unique. So no paul@walker.com or jennifer@lopez.com . Is there a way to change the code to do that?

Comment: @Patrick See updated answer. You may want to edit the question and add the above comment to the question. This is to clarify the question for everyone, instead of burying the important  clarification in the comments to one of the answers. Hopefully, this will get your question reopened (it should, IMO).

Comment: Some of the above comments (about `tr` vs `perl`) may seem out of context after the discussion with the OP and edits to the answer. These comments refer to another method which can use `tr` (the current one does not use it).

Comment: Great, thank you :)